# I needs to update the sourced config file in shell script in end of the script execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I needs to update the sourced config file in shell script in end of the script execution.
I have default date in date_cfg.lkp file.

```
'''

    sdate=2021-12-09

'''
```

My shell script file accept date as parameter and it should increment the date and update that date in above date_cfg.lkp file and it works if I don't source the file but if I do source the lkp file in script it does not updating and also same behavior in command line aswell.:

```
 '''
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    date1=$1
    cfg=~/date_cfg.lkp
    source $cfg
    date1=$(date -d"$date1 + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
            date1=$(date1 -d $date1 +"%Y-%m-%d")
            echo $date1
            echo $cfg_date
            sed -c -i "s/\($sdate *= *\).*/\1$date1/" $cfg
    '''
```

Please help me updating the sdate field stored in the lkp file with incremented date in script while sourcing and please note I needs to source the file to read some other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify the last line as follows.

```
sed -c -i "s/$sdate/$date1/" $cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

your sed command isn't good:

```
sed -i "/sdate=/ s/.*/sdate=$date1/" date_cfg.lkp
```

What is -c in the command ? I haven't this arg.